# How to secure my ColdBox application?

Tags: coldfusion, coldbox

I'm doing my first steps with ColdBox and I just got stucked. I have two database tables, users and firms and each user belongs to one firm. After a user logged in to the application, he can list every firm, but can only edit the firm he belongs to.

So how can I manage that the user only has an edit link for his firm? And how should I secure the firm handler and edit action?

I'm working with ColdBox VirtualEntityService and Coldfusion ORM. Should I write a function in the UserService which validates the users permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit permissions should be part of the session somehow and your view should contain some logic as to wether a firm is "editable" and display the edit link. Of course your controller will need to double check the user permissions when someone actually uses the edit link to make sure they do indeed have the permissions they need.

This seems like a sort of "standard logic" question and has not so much to do with Coldbox. I'm not a CB expert but I don't think there's something specifically native to CB that handles your case. This is simply about writing good controller and validation code and figuring out what to store in your users session.